# How to properly set State with Firestore getDocuments

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

When I run `checkDoc` I'm finding that my State `validDoc` will initially be set to `false`, but the second time I run it the value returns `true`.  I know the document I'm querying for is present.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
class PropertiesViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var validDoc= false

    private var db = Firestore.firestore()

    func checkDoc(docRef: String) -> Bool {

        db.collection(docRef).getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
                if querySnapshot?.count ?? 0 > 0 {
                    self.validDoc = true
                }
        }
        print("validDoc \(validDoc)")
        return validDoc
    }
}
```

Here's my return

```
validLogin false
validLogin true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that's wrong is your expectations about how `getDocuments` works.

`getDocuments` is asynchronous, and the callback (completion) you pass to it is executed *after* it returns.  Print something in the callback and it'll be more clear what's actually going on.

Given that, `checkDoc` cannot possibly return the correct value synchronously unless you do something to make it block (which you should not do).  You will need to handle all query results asynchronously.